# TFS Burn down charts

Tags: tfs, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I want to create a simple ssrs report showing rolling burndown chart for each team member in a particular iteration/sprint. So if 5 members are on the team then there should a burndown chart for each of the member depiciting the remaining effort (in hrs) against last 30 days. This will be a rolling time period from present date to last 30 days.

So, for team member A the burndown chart will have on Y-axis Effort remaining (in hrs) and on X-axix 30 dates.

Please suggest how can this be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using one of the standard process templates (e.g. MSF Agile)?  If so, there is probably an existing report that's close to what you want, either built into the system or posted on the web.  For example, here's a [large collection of sample reports](http://blogs.msdn.com/tompatton/archive/2006/05/07/591713.aspx).  (note: built for the 2005 version of MSF -- will require some tweaks for 2008)

If not, you'll have to make do with some more generic SSRS guidance, or edit your question to include the relevant pieces of your work item definition XML.

- [P&P: Creating and Customizing TFS Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc487893.aspx)
- [MSDN: Using Excel for TFS Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244713.aspx)
- [MSDN: Reporting Services tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170246(SQL.90).aspx)
- [Blog: resources for TFS report developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2007/03/26/tfs-report-developer-resources.aspx)